# The Axioms of 'Fictional Googology'

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

There have been questions on whether proper classes have cardinality (some say yes). However, I have my own axioms about it.

Firstly, we define the 'cardinality' of a proper class as the conglomerate of proper classes which form a bijection with said proper class (in ZFC). $\kappa < \lambda$ ($\kappa$, $\lambda$ cardinals) if there is an injection, but not a surjection, between a proper class with 'cardinality' $\kappa$ and one with 'cardinality' $\lambda$.

The 'cardinality' of the ordinals is called $\Omega$ (absolute infinity).

The 'cardinality' of the surreal numbers is called $\Omega_1$ (absolute one infinity).

The 'cardinality' of the Von Neumann universe is called $ↇ$ (never).

Question: Is the axiom $\Omega < \Omega_1 < ↇ$ independent of ZFC? If not, does ZFC imply it, or does it imply it is not the case? And why or why not?

(Credit to [Mathis R.V](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathis%20rv&rlz=1C1ONGR_zh-HKHK969HK969&oq=mathis%20rv&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCDEzNDdqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on) and maybe also other people for the names and symbols of the 'cardinals', but the meanings described above are probably invented by me)

Comment: There are particular formulas $\varphi,\psi$ which ZFC proves yield injections from the class of surreals to $V$ and vice versa respectively; on the other hand, there are countable models of ZFC in which no injection from $V$ to the ordinals is definable. Does that answer your question? (The blithe use of "in ZFC" hides a lot of subtlety around what your actual definitions are intended to be.)